# python: How to organize multiple classes that depend on each other?

Tags: python, class

I have a code that runs a simulation. To setup the simulation I have multiple classes:

[image]

They need to be used one after the other since information is inherited from one to the other. However, I was wondering how to best organize everything?

I would like to have one big parent class called "sim", then to access the functions in each class, I would like to be able to write:

```
sim.geometry.rectangle(...)
```

or

```
sim.run.parameter_scan(...)
```

Kind of like python packages, where one writes: `os.path.join(...)`

In order to do this, do I need to write something like:

```
class sim():
    def __init__(self):
            pass
        
    class general():
        ...
    
    class geometry():
        ...
    
    class run():
        ...
    
    etc.
```

Comment: No, don't nest the classes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay. Would you have another method to do it?